# How can i demux/remux video stream h264?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, bitstream

I'm looking for a command line in ffmpeg that demux audio and video in order to send the video in my bitstream filter and remux it in the output file. 
I have a video treatment to do in the bitstream filter without audio.
I don't find the correct grammar..
Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with the first command in your last Q?

Comment: I have found what i want, by just specify the only video stream to the bitstream filter and ffmpeg remux automatically sound and video.